# What might temporarily use 1GB of PermGen at startup?

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, permgen, string-interning

An application running under Weblogic 12c makes extremely heavy but temporary use of PermGen space during a late phase of startup.  I say "temporary" because it exhibits "saw-tooth" growth up to the PermGen limit (500MB), then instantly dropping down to a nearly-constant base level (around 300MB), graphing like this: /|/|/| .  After about 5 lengthy iterations, normal startup resumes.

Running with "-verbose:class" turned on, we see no classes being loaded or unloaded during this behavior.

What usage of PermGen might exhibit this set of symptoms?  All I can think is that for some unknown reason, around a gigabyte of interned strings are being created and then garbage-collected.

**Update**
This is running on Solaris HotSpot 1.7.  [Strings aren't interned in Java 7.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297931/interned-strings-not-in-permgen)

**Update 2**
This appears to be an issue with trying to load the classes being handled by a ServletContextInitializer, probably WebLogic-specific.  We don't have any ServletContextInitializers, nor do any of our libs - it must be part of the base WebLogic classloader space.  There are a lot in there.  I'd guess that there's a bug in error-handling of NoClassDefFound for a base class, interface, or annotation used by some class that the @HandlesTypes on the ServletContextInitializer is flagging.

Comment: What libraries/frameworks does your app use?

Comment: Feasibly something that is doing a whole bunch of runtime class instrumentation via a library like javassist or something using unusual string interning behaviour.  This may also be an affect of your jvm if you're using a non-standard one, though I've not seen any do that.

Comment: @Bill, it's a very large app with dozens of dependencies.  The only thing that I'm aware of that creates classes dynamically is JAXB.  Similarly, the only lib in use that I know does a lot of interning is JAXP (Xerces).  There's no Hibernate.  To reverse your question... What libs/frameworks would raise a flag with you, and why?

Comment: @Taylor, I thought of runtime instrumentation and JIT-compilation, but in both cases, I'd expect the allocation to be permanent - not just created and then released in PermGen space.

Comment: It can happen if a classloader is used during startup and then discarded, IIRC.  Again this is all heavily dependent on the JVM.

Comment: @Taylor, wouldn't that be logged by -verbose:class?  This is HotSpot/Solaris.

Comment: The Java-based Rhino JavaScript engine has an "as designed" permgen leak when run in non-interpreted mode.  Just throwing ideas out there in case something sticks.

Comment: @EdStaub I've used -XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading in the past.

Comment: @Taylor AFAICT `TraceClassLoading`/`TraceClassUnloading` are just finer-grained switches for `-verbose:class`.  The output is identical in format.

Comment: @EdStaub HAve you tried: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/tooldescr.html#gblmm ?

Comment: @Taylor Yeah, it just hangs.  Tried big heap, googling - no joy.